# How to use generator functions from ordinary promise based code?

Tags: generator, redux-saga

Here is a function that I can call conveniently from from a `redux-saga` saga:

```
export function* getSessionToken(username: string) {
    try {
        const session = yield call(refreshSession, username);
        return session.idToken.getJwtToken();
    } catch (error) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
function* signIn(username) {
   const jwt = yield call(getSessionToken, username);
   if (!jwt) {
       return;
   }
}
```

But say that somewhere else in my code, I wanted to achieve the same flow without using redux-saga. How would I do? Is it even possible?

Here is my best (confused and failed) attempt:

```
function signIn(username) {
    const generator = getSessionToken(username);
    let result = generator.next();
    while (!result.done) {
        result = it.next();
    }
    result.then((jwt) => {
        if (!jwt) {
            return;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible (unless you decide to deal with all the effects yourself), there is no reason `getSessionToken` needs to be saga though, so you can just rewrite it to normal function and then you can use it everywhere.